# How to convert a script using VarSetCapacity to AHK v2?

Tags: multiple-monitors, autohotkey, window

I have been using the script [Advanced Window Snap](https://gist.github.com/AWMooreCO/1ef708055a11862ca9dc), which snaps windows to various places of the monitor, which uses the function [GetMonitorIndexFromWindow](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/69464-how-to-determine-a-window-is-in-which-monitor/?p=440355) to determine in which monitor a window is located.

I am converting it to AHKv2.

So far, I could get this:

```
GetMonitorIndexFromWindow(windowHandle) {
    ; Starts with 1.
    monitorIndex := 1

; Original
;    VarSetCapacity(&monitorInfo, 40)
; My try
    monitorInfo := Buffer(40)
    NumPut("Uint", 40, monitorInfo)

    if (monitorHandle := DllCall("MonitorFromWindow", "uint", windowHandle, "uint", 0x2))
        && DllCall("GetMonitorInfoA", "uint", monitorHandle, "uint", &monitorInfo) {
        monitorLeft   := NumGet(monitorInfo,  4, "Int")
        monitorTop    := NumGet(monitorInfo,  8, "Int")
        monitorRight  := NumGet(monitorInfo, 12, "Int")
        monitorBottom := NumGet(monitorInfo, 16, "Int")
        workLeft      := NumGet(monitorInfo, 20, "Int")
        workTop       := NumGet(monitorInfo, 24, "Int")
        workRight     := NumGet(monitorInfo, 28, "Int")
        workBottom    := NumGet(monitorInfo, 32, "Int")
        isPrimary     := NumGet(monitorInfo, 36, "Int") & 1

        monitorCount := MonitorGetCount

        Loop %monitorCount% {
            tempMon := MonitorGet(%A_Index%, &tempMonLeft, &tempMonTop, &tempMonRight, &tempMonBottom)

            ; Compare location to determine the monitor index.
            if ((monitorLeft = tempMonLeft) and (monitorTop = tempMonTop)
                and (monitorRight = tempMonRight) and (monitorBottom = tempMonBottom)) {
                monitorIndex := A_Index
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return monitorIndex
}
```

but it doesn't work because the way I replaced VarSetCapacity(monitorInfo, 40) doesn't seem to be what the DllCall expects.

I also tried strings, or buffers, but the DllCall (the second one) complains about "Error: Expected a Number but got a VarRef.".

In fact, I'm not even sure this DllCall is still needed, maybe the functions https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Monitor.htm could be used to skip it altogether.

How can I convert the function to a syntax compatible with AHK v2?

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?style=19&t=125472 someone else did the same, 5 years ago

Comment: @Gantendo but I am already using the example provided there, see Buffer and NumPut("Uint", 40, monitorInfo), and I get the error I mentioned

Comment: There's a newer version : [Hyper Window Snap](https://github.com/glenviewjeff/HyperWindowSnap). It may be for AHK V1, but even then it may be better as a starting point. For automatic conversion see [AHK v2 Script Converter](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=25100).